# MySQL PDO INSERT ... SELECT IF statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

EDIT: stupid variable name mismatch. Simple mistakes made even after years of coding.

```
   $query = "
    INSERT INTO table1 (team_id, user_id, team_leader, start_date)
    SELECT b.team_id,
           a.user_id,
           IF (a.agent_id = :leader, 1, 0),
           :startdate
    FROM table2 a
    LEFT JOIN table3 b ON a.ccb_team_id = b.ccb_team_id
    WHERE b.team_active = 1
      AND a.user_active = 1
      AND b.metro_id = :metroid 
      AND a.ccb_team_id = :teamid
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
       UPDATE team_leader = VALUES(team_leader)";
```

Data:

```
$query_data = array(
            ':metroid' => $metro_id,
            ':leader' => $a->ccb_leader_id,
            ':startdate' => $datetime,
            ':teamid' => $a->ccb_team_id
        );
```

If I try the above query in phpMyAdmin with the actual data where the PDO variables are, it works fine with the team_leader set correctly to 1 for the relevant users. Running this in PHP CLI, it doesn't work, all team_leader fields are reverted to 0.

I've verified the `$a->ccb_team_leader` contains the correct information. Do PDO variables not work in IF statements?

Edit: so it seems this is actually some kind of object problem when using it in my PDO query. The object $a from simplexml outputs the value fine but not when it's used in the query....

Comment: Field names and table names cannot be binded. Over.

Comment: It's not a field or table name, it's a value. IF(a.agent_id = 123456,1,0).

Comment: `:startdate FROM table2`

Comment: literals may appear in SELECT list.

Comment: try case instead of `IF(a.agent_id=:leader,1,0)`?  `case when a.agent_id=:leader then 1 else 0 end`  what data type is a.agent_Id and :leader?  perhaps the if function is getting caught up on a data type mismatch?

Comment: I cannot see anything obviously incorrect. I assume you have checked the PHP variables for being valid. Try setting the PDO connection setting to 'emulates' as true if you have set it to false. Otherwise would you mind providing table definitions with the some test data so that we can run it easily? see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I also cannot find a fault. Even if the data type of *$a->ccb_team_leader* were string, it should still work.

Comment: I've added table definitions to question

Comment: I tried ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to TRUE with no change. I just noticed that the updated_timestamp changes for the rows that should be changed, which means it's actually performing an update to the row apparently but it's still 0 in the field. It wouldn't update the row at all and change the timestamp if it was meant to stay at 0.

Comment: More testing. If I hard code the entire query, it works fine under PDO. If I add the leader value into a variable and insert into the query directly it works fine. If I use the $a->ccb_leader_id object it does not work, even if I do $val = intval($a->ccb_leader_id) and use $val instead, still inserts 0. Simply doing an echo $a->ccb_leader_id outputs the correct value in the shell that I'm trying to match.

The $a object comes from an $xml created by simplexml_load_string.

Comment: Had a chance to revisit this finally and although I did manage to confirm my use of PDO literals was fine but I (and no one else) picked up the fact that I had simply and stupidly mismatched the object variable name.

$a->ccb_leader_id was wrong, it was $a->ccb_team_leader which I even wrote here and I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your query so that the parameters are in the where clause. See the examples in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php.

Either that or you can escape the literal on your own and add it directly into your query string.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware PDO bindings could only exist in the WHERE clause. I'll escape it myself. Shouldn't it give an error though? It processes both the IF and CASE versions with no errors.

Comment: @DaveK,  You can use `bind` param/values as `value replacements` anywhere in the query. You are not restricted to the `where` clause.

Comment: I was about to ask about that because it's still not working. I've tried IF or CASE in the SELECT with the variable added into the query string rather then PDO and it's still not working on CLI but fine on phpmyadmin so it's something else I'm missing.....

Comment: I couldn't find a better source yet, but this [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49406) and its fix also demonstrate that bound values may occur in the `SELECT` list, not only in the `WHERE` clause.